# jQuery - How to check if input is there?

Tags: jquery, html-table

Simple task here, but I can't get it right: If a table-cell is clicked, I need to check whether it contains an `input` field or not. If it's not there, a new one should be created.

So far I got this:

```
$("tbody td").bind("click", function(){
  $this = $(this);
  var newInput = $(document.createElement("input")).attr("class", "input-small");
  $this.append(newInput);
})
```

This works, but as you can see, it misses the test if an input is already there. I already tried various methods including `if($this.text.length){...}`, `if($this.val().hasClass("input-small") == true){...}` but they all fail. So how do I do it right? Whats the right way to check if the clicked cell contains an input field?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Something like the following will work

```
if ($this.find('input').length) { 
    // the td clicked contains an <input>
}
```

`$this` is a jQuery object that wraps the current `<td>` element (referenced by `this`), so we need to look into this element in the DOM to see if it contains an `<input>` element. If it does, the `.length` property will be greater than 0 and thus a truthy value.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($(this).children("input").length == 0) //the cell doesn't contain any input elements.
```

Answer (score 1):

Russ Cam has the answer for you (upvote him!), I just wanted to help you optimize the code some what.

```
// .click just points to jquerys .on function, so calling it directly is faster.
$('tbody td').on('click', function() {
     // always declare your variables properly, some javascript engines could have issues, however excellent that you are caching $(this)
     var $this = $(this),
         newInput = $('<input class="input-small"');

     // .lenght will return false if the length is 0, so no need to compare it to an int
     if(!$this.find('input').length) {
         newInput.appendTo($this);
     }
});
```

edit: fixed logic

Comment: Thanks for the commented code! After fixing newInput to `$('<input type="text" class="input-small">');` it nearly worked. Problem is I had to do it like `if($this.find('input').length == false)` because otherwise it did not work. Any reason for that? (Because what you've written sounds logical to me!)

Comment: Seems very strange, sure there isn't a typo somewhere?
I made a fidde here http://jsfiddle.net/LxHK9/ , where you can see it in action.

Oh nevermind, its the logic in my code that's wrong, it should be
if(!$this.find('input').length)

as it is now it checks if its there, and then appends it. Not the other way around.

Comment: haha yeah, seems to be a logical error on my side! `if($this.find('input').length){...}` - this means an input is there. So if I put `newInput.appendTo($this);` it's basically senseless for my purpose. But with if-else it works like a charm! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if($(this).find('input').length > 0){

    var newInput = $(document.createElement("input")).attr("class", "input-small");
      $this.append(newInput);
}
```